# Retrofit2 - Sending Array of Type T in a GET request

Tags: android, retrofit2

I need to send an array of type `User[]` in the body of a GET request using retrofit2. This is what the final payload must look like:

```
body: {
  "data_id": 1,
  "data_provider": "string_value",
  "users": [
    {
      user_id: 1,
      name: 'name'
    },
    {
      user_id: 1,
      name: 'name'
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

**Current API implementation looks like this:**

```
@GET("api/users/submit.json")
Call<UserData> submitData(@Query("data_id") int data_id, @Query("data_provider") String data_provider, @Query("users[]") User[] users);
```

**Arraylist code:**

```
//Converting the ArrayList<User> usersList to an array
User[] userArray = usersList.toArray(new User[0]);
//The userArray is passed to the retrofit API along with the other request values (data_id, data_provider)
```

Upon logging the retrofit request, `data_id` and `data_provider` are correctly sent except for the User array. The user array looks like this:

> api/users/submit.json?data_id=1&data_provider=test&users[]=com.testapp.models.User@7d57487

How can I send an array of type `User` in the GET request body?

Comment: Try converting users[] to JSON Array and then send the request to server.

Comment: JSONArray userArray = new JSONArray(userArray);

Comment: @RakshitNawani That requires min API 19. Mine is 16. I don't want to raise it to 19

Comment: Ok try converting the Array to GSON
String user= new Gson().toJson(users[]);

Comment: data_id and data_provider are not querying param they are part of body so you should combine all these values in body object and pass it with @Body in retrofit service.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887212/android-retrofit-get-query-arraylist/44887469?noredirect=1#comment76771974_44887469

Answer (score 2):

You can send User object in request body using @Body annotation

Roughly it would look like this:

Your User Model

```
class User {
}
```

Users class which stores the list of Users

```
class RequestBody {
int data_id;
String data_provider;
List<User> users;
}

@POST("api/users/submit.json")
Call<UserData> submitData(@Body RequestBody requestbody);
```

You can read more about it in details here:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-objects-in-request-body

Comment: Are you sure boss data_id and data_provider  in Query param as the structure, he provides initially show it should be part of the body? other than that your answer is right.

Comment: Cool, thanks for pointing it out mate. I have fixed it now...cheers

Comment: I tried this but retrofit doesn't send the request is not sent at all. Are you sure this works for GET? I thought it's only meant for POST

Comment: are you sure it is a GET API, It should be POST/PUT API as you post the data in request body and not appending it in URL. Try to change annotation with @POST and see if it works.

Comment: The endpoint is GET. I am supposed to append it as Query string

Answer (score 1):

For this payload:-

```
body: {
  "data_id": 1,
  "data_provider": "string_value",
  "users": [
    {
      user_id: 1,
      name: 'name'
    },
    {
      user_id: 1,
      name: 'name'
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Api structure should be like this:-

```
public class ReqBody{
    int data_id;
    String data_provider;
    User[] users;
}

@POST("api/users/submit.json")
Call<UserData> submitData(@Body ReqBody reqBody);
```

If your requirement is something else please attach the proper details for API as at some point you want to send **data_id** and **data_provider** in Query param and in the structure you have defined them as part of the body.
If they are part of the body then it should be work like this.

Comment: Okay trying this. I'll reply afterwards.

Comment: I tried this but retrofit doesn't send the request is not sent at all. Are you sure this works for GET? I thought it's only meant for POST

Comment: Ok, Are you sure your API is GET as you can't pass the Body with GET request.

Comment: Can you please add the complete description for API which you have got from your backend team